# Using .pbf Vector Tiles generated with t-rex with OpenLayers errors with "Uncaught Error: Unimplemented type: 7"

Tags: vector-tiles, openlayers, pbf

I generated .pbf vector tiles with t-rex's `generate` command.
I then uploaded them to a directory served with the Apache HTTP server.

Trying to use the tiles with OpenLayers (6.4.3) resulted in no tiles being displayed but a huge list of JavaScript errors in the browser console:

`"Uncaught Error: Unimplemented type: 7"` somewhere around:

```
skip index.js:211
readFields index.js:46
rg MVT.js:309
readFields index.js:44
readFeatures MVT.js:259
```

The layer is specified as:

```
new ol.layer.VectorTile({
            source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
              format: new ol.format.MVT(),
              tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 22}),
              tilePixelRatio: 16,
              url: 'mvtcache/layer/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf'
            })
          })
```

What does that error mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the tiles are GZIP compressed but Apache, when serving them, does not send a `"Content-Encoding: gzip"` header in the response. This seems to make OpenLayers expect non-compressed tiles (even though that seems to be the standard format for MVT) and results in that non-descript error.

A server-side fix is making Apache add that header, e. g. with a `.htaccess` file in the tiles directory containing the following rule:

```
<Files "*.pbf">
  Header set Content-Encoding: gzip
</Files>
```

Comment: I added the .htaccess file inside the root of the tiles directory but I still take this message.Thoughts?

Comment: Best check if your server really responds with the correct headers for the tile requests.